# Create an interface/type alias with an exhaustive list of properties that comes from a union type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

Imagine I have this array, which is the "source of truth" for my action names:

```
const ACTION_NAMES = ["ACTION_1","ACTION_1","ACTION_3"] as const;

// I'M USING "as const" SO I CAN GET A UNION TYPE OUT OF IT

type ACTION_NAMES = typeof ACTION_NAMES[number];

// THIS IS "ACTION_1" | "ACTION_2" | "ACTION_3"
```

Now I want an interface/type which should have all these properties (exhaustive), as in:

```
type SOME_TYPE = {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

interface ACTION_PAYLOADS {  // COULD ALSO USE type alias HERE
  ACTION_1: {propA: string, propB: number},
  ACTION_2: {propC: boolean},
  ACTION_3: {propD: string}
}
```

Is there any type I can `extend` the `ACTION_PAYLOADS` interface from, so that Typescript will make sure that all `ACTION_1 2 and 3` properties will be present, and all of their values will `extend` the `SOME_TYPE` type?

The idea is that Typescript ideally should complain if I'm missing one of the `ACTION_` properties, and also if one of the values isn't of type `SOME_TYPE`. Also it wouldn't allow me to add any extra properties, for example `ACTION_4`.

It feels like I'm type checking a type. But can't I do it with some mapped type? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some helper types to trigger a compiler error if your interface doesn't conform to the desired constraints.  It looks like this:

```
type Extends<T extends U, U> = void;
type MutuallyExtends<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = void;

type CheckKeysOfActionPayloads =
    MutuallyExtends<keyof ACTION_PAYLOADS, ACTION_NAMES>; // ok
type CheckValuesOfActionPayloads =
    Extends<ACTION_PAYLOADS[ACTION_NAMES], SOME_TYPE>; // ok
```

Here, `CheckKeysOfActionPayloads` will only compile if the keys of `ACTION_PAYLOADS` and the type `ACTION_NAMES` mutually extend each other... for a union of literals this means they need to be identical.

And `CheckValuesOfActionPayload` will only compiler if the values of `ACTION_PAYLOADS` (at the `ACTION_NAMES` keys) are assignable to `SOME_TYPE`.

---

For concreteness I'm going to change `SOME_TYPE` to be something that can fail, and also let's make sure that `ACTION_NAMES` has `"ACTION_2"` in it (as opposed to your example code):

```
const ACTION_NAMES = ["ACTION_1", "ACTION_2", "ACTION_3"] as const;
type ACTION_NAMES = typeof ACTION_NAMES[number];
type SOME_TYPE = {
    [key: string]: string | number | boolean
}
```

Let's see what happens if we mess up `ACTION_PAYLOADS`.  First, if we miss a key:

```
interface ACTION_PAYLOADS {
    ACTION_1: { propA: string, propB: number },
    // where's ACTION_2?
    ACTION_3: { propD: string }
}

type CheckKeysOfActionPayloads =
    MutuallyExtends<keyof ACTION_PAYLOADS, ACTION_NAMES>; // error!
//      ----------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type "ACTION_2" is not assignable to type "ACTION_1" | "ACTION_3"
```

Or if we have an extra key:

```
interface ACTION_PAYLOADS {
    ACTION_1: { propA: string, propB: number },
    ACTION_2: { propC: boolean },
    ACTION_3: { propD: string },
    ACTION_4: { propE: number } // what's this?
}

type CheckKeysOfActionPayloads =
    MutuallyExtends<keyof ACTION_PAYLOADS, ACTION_NAMES>; // error!
// ---------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type "ACTION_4" is not assignable to type "ACTION_1" | "ACTION_2" | "ACTION_3"
```

And finally if the keys are right but a value is wrong:

```
interface ACTION_PAYLOADS {
    ACTION_1: { propA: string, propB: number },
    ACTION_2: { propC: Date }, // what's this?
    ACTION_3: { propD: string }
}

type CheckValuesOfActionPayloads =
    Extends<ACTION_PAYLOADS[ACTION_NAMES], SOME_TYPE>; // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'
```

You can see that in all those cases you get an error that can hopefully be used to help you fix the code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggYQCoEkDyA5A+huBZAUQGUYBeGAbQCJFVMsBGKgGhhuXWwCYW3bOsAZioBdGAEMIMUJCgBuALAAoKAE8ADgFN4HerkIlyarSABmOutn3EKYAK4BbAEaaATiMUqN2omkJYkAE0ABQIyGABvZRgYygBrTVUALhhoVwBLMABzERS0zKyYAB8Ye2c3YpgnEBAAG01xMGUAX2VlMHEHTQh1cWBtAHEagBNItqVYmEyoN1M+7X56YLhAgBk0OAAREiiJydjF7AYUiJh1VxB1ODyoDOzWc8uAIRSyl1cYZuZo-ZjDrC4JzOF3UCBS1TqDTAn2+e1+-0EQMe6k2NzuhVacM+40mxm0BAAHjMwMMIAAeJAwTREzQkqQAVVY9IAfOEAG4gdLDTy47wwPB2KB2cS1WqqQnE0kUqk0ukwRnymWSqQANVYKvCSFZ5A5XM8PxieJgCAAFppgHEANKJCBoUxwYBQdLgYLiVS1EDiUlkA37AVCkViiW0qUJVRmCwCZZrDbbVj-axEZlyGAAelTMBAcV9RtN5riKpFdm6dodTpdbo9XqkpF9k2DdLJ-2j6y2RAoCfwxBErF8-iCoWTaYzWfGmPanW6vX6-PSEAgBWtqjGWOms3mkaWK1b2xXvz+uiOSJB11StwKDxBL1KjneMLrB0PQmPl1RZ-R2Kx46xRobUsp1LKvKTLajAurcjmfL+sKorirK-5KiGDJMohcpqjAGrkFq7KchBSiQVoxpmhaS62vajrOmArrup63q1likzQYGcHKmSYYRs226xkQ8ZPomQ7plSrgXK4ACEvqCfsAC0MmyXJ8kKYpCmsgAfmp6kaWpEkZkgfLsJYAJUFMUhgCAsCSAuWQdE49QwFAIB2Xp-xMJU+kCMIOKxLmxEFkWJbkeWVGVrRNYPjEf7kpxMZth2fFdkQPYwH2BABCEBDJi04wdF0PQbhKrjiEue6xGurhzDOUU7jsYWbkekTApcp75PcDXqNebwVF8NX-IC9XImCVQ1PUjT3gxj4GYifUgm+zUYrC+61VgAAsL7qAQry3p1vrfryhERdKgFIcB8qgeBPJeVBgowUG8HkgBt3HfSqHeuhmEwNhOq4fqP58nmJE2qWFEVjR1Y+mNMRMbB+3seYlXcbxBn8SmgluCJ4lYoJSmKapmm43jWkYzpTlPktRlzqUZkSPO6RWeINnaPZjmEW59AuSULPcEZ7MIlQnmGr9PmFrUxZkWWlHUVWdE1ftcMxZ2BiJclqWDp437ZVOG5PF6QvFvVvqleVCxPi23HFfCT7HFNjVoherXtZtHxdeDi29ac-UpJs4gzKNC0IqtM3ntkn6TDtF17bdB0PQqLI4XqBHaJDN2sfdQHR89qrqpqp1fXzTPaH9VoAwF4vBaD9ELYnLFIWxiQccbXFtgjAhI8OmbZj9hEFzr-li8Dkuhc7Mv19F2yxYj8WK34KUDulyMZqjIBidpMDYzA+PrxvBOTIJumEQA5J7Mx78ZFPmdTtP03ZDlGnvs2VB1HwlBCw1gHvLRAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, jcalz! I've been trying to find a workaround to this for a while. That does the trick.